# Symfony pass two models to route

Tags: routes, symfony1

I have this routing.yml:

```
post:
  class:   sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options: { model: BlogPost }
```

I need this url:
    /company/24/mycompany/blog/post/13.

How how I can pass to my route 2 models to generate following route:

```
//Test route example
post_show:
  url: /company/:id/:title_slug/blog/post/:post_id
  param:   { module: company, action: show }
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: MyCompany }
```

How I can describe second model here, to get attributes to the URL? Is it possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it before, with a custom route class, a bit like this:

```
<?php

class sfDoctrineMultiRoot extends sfRequestRoute {

  public function matchesUrl($url, $context = array()) {

    if (false === $parameters = parent::matchesUrl($url, $context)) {
      return false;
    }
    $company = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Company')
            ->find($parameters['company_id']);

    if (!$company) {
      return false;
    }

    $blog = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Blog')
            ->find($parameters['blog_id']);

    if (!$blog) {
      return false;
    }

    $this->company = $company;
    $this->blog = $blog;

    return $parameters;
  }

  public function getCompany() {
    return $this->company;
  }

  public function getBlog() {
    return $this->blog;
  }


  public function generate($params, $context = array(), $absolute = false)
  {

    foreach ($params as $key=>$param) {
      if (method_exists($param, 'getRawValue')) {
        $params[$key] = $param->getRawValue();
      }
    }

    if (isset($params['company']) && $params['company'] instanceof Company) {
      $params['company_id'] = $params['company']->getId();
    }
    unset($params['company']);

    if (isset($params['blog']) && $params['blog'] instanceof Blog) {
      $params['blog_id'] = $params['blog']->getId();
      unset($params['blog']);
    }
    unset($params['blog']);

    return parent::generate($params, $context, $absolute);
  }

}
```

You have to use something like this in routing.yml:

```
test:
  url: /company/:company_id//blog/:blog_id
  class: sfDoctrineMultiRoot
  param:   { module: company, action: show }
```

You can generate urls via url_for and link_to like this:

```
url_for('test', array('blog'=>BlogObject, 'company'=>'CompanyObject'));
```

or

```
url_for('test', array('blog_id'=>1, 'company_id'=>2));
```

And to retrieve the objects in your action you can call:

```
$this->getRoute()->getBlog();
```

or

```
$this->getRoute()->getCompany();
```

Comment: Thanks, but where I need to put this new route class?And how I tell to symfony to use it? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't really matter where you put it - symfony's auto loader will find it. I'd recommend making a folder in your project's lib folder called "route" and putting it in there (file called sfDoctrineMultiRoot.class.php ). You may need to clear your cache after adding the file.

Comment: This is neither generic nor extensible. I support the idea of a multi-object doctrine route, but it should act similarly to sfDoctrineRoute, with the ability to specify models and methods.

Comment: Whilst I agree with jeremy above - I happened to have the code already, so posted it to be helpful. It could be tidied up to be generic etc, maybe one day I will, but sometimes it just needs to be enough to work. And the day I wrote this was one of these days. Besides, I believe it is better than jeremy's solution, which so far is "start it from scratch".  /rant.